# Can't boot windows after ubuntu 'reinstall', windows is on a separate drive, tried repair disc and most other stuff

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

So one drive has ubuntu and mint (500GB), and the other windows 10(1TB). I wiped former and reinstalled ubuntu and installed mint, and now I can't boot windows on the other drive from startup anymore.

I have:

- Ran repair disc
- Set up a partition for the bootloader with gparted and made sure the bootloader was in that.
- Ran `fdisk -l` on terminal and updated grub. when I did this it detected a 'windows xp loader'? or something, but updating grub hasn't done anything.
- Used windows recovery disk and ran `bootrec.exe/fixmbr` and `fixboot` from the console.

I can boot up either mint or ubuntu from the menu after selecting their drive, but the windows drive doesn't show, and when it does it is just a no drive device found error message when ran. I dunno what else to do other than fresh install windows.

I've had this problem before and honestly can't remmber what I did, but know that on the boot menu were the options for the 500GB drive which actually ran windows for some reason (pretty sure repair disc did this by magic, dunno why it's not working now), and just one option that said 'ubuntu' or something.

Comment: Maybe you have the OSes installed in different boot modes (BIOS (legacy) vs UEFI).

Comment: @wjandrea that might be it yeah, but how do I fix that?